# C - fopen invalid file

Tags: c, fopen

I am wondering, how to check if I am opening file which exists with fopen? I want to diplay some message, when user selects file with bad name. Is must be some simple checking, but I am not able to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your param list:

```
FILE pFile ;
```

then:

```
  pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");

if (pFile == NULL)
printf("No Such File !! ");
```

Comment: that's not a good error message at all. "no such file" is only one of the possible failures.

Comment: This is the only possible option, because if file is corrupt he wont load as a program for example, but he will be able to read its characters char by char(or line or more).

Comment: No it's not. It could be a permission problem on the file or the path. It could be a resource allocation error also (fopen can call `malloc`, which can fail). Saying "no such file" when the problem could be completely different is bad practice and will make debugging harder.

Comment: Other possible errors (from the linux manpage for `open`, which are also possible errors for `fopen()`): Too many symbolic links, Number of maximum open files for this process reached, pathname is too long, Number of maximum open files for the system reached, not enough kernel memory, invalid name for filesystem, file is too large.

Comment: Much better to use perror() than printf() in this case.

Answer (score 3):

When `fopen` fails, it returns `NULL` and sets `errno` to indicate the type of error.

Check the return value, and if it's `NULL` check `errno`. You can use functions like `perror` or `strerror` to display simple messages about those errors.

Answer (score 1):

To make it even clearer:

```
f = fopen("some-file-name.ext", "r");
if (f == NULL) reporterror();
```

But, probably you don't want to use `fopen` for checking existence and access right. You should look at `stat` and `access`.  Both available in C libraries and using man

Comment: Note that access and stat are not C (they are POSIX).

Comment: @Jens - You're right.  I remember access being on every platform I worked on but it apparently isn't standard.

Answer (score 1):

See [the possible errors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) for `open`:

However, I think you'll have a hard time finding a way to determine that a filename was invalid. On most systems (except Windows) any string that's not overly long is potentially valid (modulo `/` being interpreted as a path separator).

Answer (score 1):

fopen() function opens the file whose name is specified in the parameter filename and associates it with a stream that can be identified in future operations by the FILE pointer returned.

```
FILE *try_to_open = fopen("Document.txt", "r");    //READ ONLY
```

If the file is successfully opened, function returns a pointer to a FILE object that can be used to identify the stream on future operations; otherwise, a null pointer is returned. So, if you want to check that file has been opened correctly, just check that pointer is not null, in this way:

```
if (try_to_open == NULL){
    puts("Opening file failed.");
} else {
    puts("File opened successfully.");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: the returned `FILE*` pointer will be `null` if file doesn't exists.

Of course this assumes you are opening it in `r`, read mode.

Comment: Yes, but it will be as well `NULL` if he doesn't have appropriate permissions for example.